# Keeping a list synchronized on an unreliable network

Tags: python, network-programming, messaging

I recently wrote an [IRC bot](https://github.com/d33tah/wikispy/blob/master/irc/bot.py) for the Wikipedia edit notification channels. I am a bit worried that it is rather easy to take down though - if I experience downtime, I lose the record of what was edited and this is why I run the bot on more than one VPS. However, in case of a failure, merging the data would be a pain. This leads to a question: is there a library that would allow me to build a network of those bots that would exchange such messages:

`{"title": "Tourism in Egypt", "ip": "142.33.254.2", "timestamp": "2015-05-11T16:27:05.250456", "id": "661862110", "channel": "#en.wikipedia"}`

...in a way that would be fault tollerable? What I would like to achieve is a situation where if a single node goes down, the other queues up the messages which are then sent as soon as the node goes back up. Ultimately, I would like to keep a single file where all the messages are logged, not necessarily in an ordered fashion.

Comment: Why not use a networked database with replication to store data? Then it will handle all that for you.

Comment: I use a separate database to store all the results which I specifically tweaked due to the amount of data there is, so that would involve two databases then. This sounds a little complex for a queue implementation. I like the idea of using external solutions though.

Comment: Have you looked at [zmq](http://zeromq.org/bindings:python)?